# mitt event bus with combobox usage in VueJS 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, publish-subscribe, eventemitter

I have configured `mitt` as a global event bus in my `main.js`:

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from './App.vue'
import mitt from "mitt";
const emitter = mitt();
const app = createApp(App);
app.config.globalProperties.emitter = emitter;
app.mount("#app");
```

And I'm publishing an event using the `event-bus` from the **child component** as follows:

```html
<template>
    <div class= "combobox">
        <label for={{selector_name}}>
            <p>{{ selector_title }}</p>
        </label>
        <select :name="selector_name"  :id="selector_id" :disabled="disabled" @change="onChange">
            <option v-for="(opt, index) in selector_options" :key="`opt ${index}`">
            {{ opt }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'ComboBox',
    data() { 
        return {
            disabled: false,
        };
    },
    props: {
        selector_title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        selector_name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        selector_id: {
            type: String,
            default: "combobox"
        },
        selector_options: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onChange(event){
            this.emitter.emit('lock-combobox', { id: this.selector_id });
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Then I try to subscribe to the event in the **parent component** as follows:

```html
<template>
<div id="controls" class="param">
    <div class="control" id="combobox1">
        <ComboBox
        selector_title = "Pattern"
        selector_name = "pattern"
        :selector_options="['complex', 'simple']"
        selector_id="combo1"
        ref="combo1"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="control" id="combobox2">
        <ComboBox
        selector_title = "Hand"
        selector_name = "pattern"
        :selector_options="['Left', 'Right']"
        selector_id="combo2"
        ref="combo2"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="control" id="speedslider">
        <SpeedSlider/>
    </div>
    <div class="control" id="startstop">
        <StartStopButton/>
    </div>
    <div class = control id="emergency">
        <Emergency/>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import ComboBox from '../components/ComboBox.vue';

export default {
    name: "Controls",
    components: {
        ComboBox,
    },
    created() {
        this.emitter.on('lock-combobox', (event) => {
            this.$refs.event.id.disabled = true;
        });
    },
}
</script>
```

But whenever I change the option in the Combobox, I get an error:

```bash
Uncaught TypeError: undefined has no properties
```

Can you please tell me how can I solve that? thanks in advance.

Comment: `this.$refs.event` I don't see a ref called `event` in your html template anywhere.

Comment: @bassxzero true, the error is caused by this line, the event source is the child component using the global event bus from mitt, and the `$refs` are from the parent component, but I'm not sure how can I combine the `ref id` emitted by the child component and access it from the parent component

Comment: Does this work? `this.$refs[event.id].disabled`

Comment: @bassxzero I have tried your suggestion, and still I get the same error.

Comment: Add a `console.log(event.id)` to your event handler and make sure you're sending the correct ref id.

Comment: `console.log("Hi")` doesn't tell us anything. We already knew the function is getting executed, that's where the error is.

Comment: @bassxzero I have updated the code in the question and now I can get: `console.log(event.id)`  `id: "combobox"` in the parent, but the error is still when I change the selection.

Comment: Looks like you're not passing in a `selector_id` and it's using the default (`combobox`), which doesn't exist as a ref in your html template.

Comment: @bassxzero true, I have updated my question with the `selector_id` fix, and now I don't get any error using your suggestion `this.$refs[event.id].disabled`, but the property is not changed, the combo box selection is not `disabled`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're setting the disabled property of the `div` element wrapping the `ComboBox`.

Comment: @bassxzero excellent remark, I have changed the `ref` position to inside the `<combobox>` in my question, but by now I have started to get an error `uncaught TypeError: proxy set handler returned false for property '"disabled"'` when changing the selection of the combo box component`

Comment: So you're trying to disable the ComboBox after a selection is made?

Comment: @bassxzero true, I want to control the property `disable` by emitting an event using event-bus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @bassxzero suggestions the solution:

#### child

```html
<template>
  <div class="combobox">
    <label for="{{selector_name}}">
      <p>{{ selector_title }}</p>
    </label>
    <select
      :name="selector_name"
      :id="selector_id"
      :disabled="disabled"
      @change="lockCombo"
      v-if="!option"
    >
      <option selected value disabled>--select--</option>
      <option v-for="(opt, index) in selector_options" :key="`opt ${index}`">
        {{ opt }}
      </option>
    </select>
    <select :name="selector_name" :id="selector_id" disabled="true" v-else>
      <option selected value disabled>{{ option }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { store } from "../js/store.js";

export default {
  name: "ComboBox",
  data() {
    return {
      disabled: false,
    };
  },
  props: {
    selector_title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    selector_name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    selector_id: {
      type: String,
      default: "combobox",
    },
    selector_options: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    option: {
      type: String,
      //required: true
    },
  },
  methods: {
    lockCombo(event) {
      this.emitter.emit("lock-combobox", {
        id: this.selector_id,
        value: event.target.value,
      });
      const log = {
        time_stamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        message: "ComboBox Choice [" + event.target.value + "] Was selected!",
        color: "orange",
        name: store.logs.length,
      };
      store.logs.push(log);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

#### Parent

```cpp
created() {
        this.emitter.on('lock-combobox', (event) => {
            if (event.id === "combo1") {
                this.$refs.combo1.disabled = true;
                store.pattern = event.value;
            }
            else if (event.id === "combo2") {
                this.$refs.combo2.disabled = true;
                store.arm = event.value;
            }
        });
        this.emitter.off('lock-combobox', (event) => {
            if (event.id === "combo1") {
                this.$refs.combo1.disabled = true;
                store.pattern = event.value;
            }
            else if (event.id === "combo2") {
                this.$refs.combo2.disabled = true;
                store.arm = event.value;
            }
        });
}
```